# Trouble paging an API with promise.all (works only once)

Tags: javascript, api, promise, paging, request-promise

So I'm asking Spotify for data about some playlists, where the max return payload size is 50. So I'd like to call `getPages`, and keep calling it recursively `while !payload.length === 50`. FYI rp = request-promise which does what it sounds like - makes a request and returns a promise for that request.

My code works well if I execute it once, but when I add more than one promise to the chain, the data storage gets messed up. Out of frustration I pointed the caches to separate keys in `cacheIT` (each key is a playlist id, stored at the key is an array of every track I fetched for said key) thinking that I just had some bad references, but that didn't help. Feels like I'm missing something basic here...

```
let req = {}; req.body = {}; req.body.playlists = [];
req.body.playlists.push({id:"0fEQxXtJS7aTK4qrxznjAJ"});
req.body.playlists.push({id:"0sJK4pWqr7bnQ0fgxGmJrh"});

let cacheIT = {};

function getPages(options) {
    console.log(options.uri);
    return rp(options).then(data => {
        cacheIT[options.playlist_id].concat(data.items);
        console.log("data",data.items.length);
        console.log("cacheIT",cacheIT[options.playlist_id].length);

        if (!(data.items.length === 50))
            return options.store;
        else
            options.offset = options.offset + offset_base ;
        options.uri =  options.url +
            "?fields=items.track(id,name,artists)&limit="+ options.limit +
            "&offset=" + options.offset;
        return getPages(options);
    });
}

req.body.playlists.forEach(function(playlist){
    options.url =  url1 + playlist.id + url2;
    options.uri = options.url + "?fields=items.track(id,name,artists)&limit=" +             options.limit + "&offset=" + options.offset;
    options.offset = 0;options.limit = 50;
    options.playlist_id = playlist.id;

    cacheIT[options.playlist_id] = [];
    options.store = cacheIT[options.playlist_id];
    promises.push(getPages(options));
});

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function(results) {
        console.log("results",results.length);
        //one of them has 38 records, and the other 148
        //so here I would expect there to be two arrays in results
        //one would have length 38, the other 148
        results.forEach(function(r){
            console.log(r.length);
        });
        //res.send(cacheIT);
    })  .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("err");
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: You can spot potential errors if you properly indent your code.

Comment: `cacheIT[options.playlist_id].concat(data.items);` doesn't do anything but create a new array that will then be discarded. Use `push` or assign the result of `concat` to something.

Answer (score 0):

`getPages` returns a promise in the form of `rp(options)` and your `promise.all` will be resolved at that level only. If you want chaining of requests, I suggest you use `async/await`.

```
async function getPages(options) {
    console.log(options.uri);
    let data = await rp(options);
    cacheIT[options.playlist_id].concat(data.items);

    console.log("data",data.items.length);
    console.log("cacheIT",cacheIT[options.playlist_id].length);

    if (data.items.length !== 50)
        return options.store;
    else {
        options.offset = options.offset + offset_base ;
        options.uri =  options.url +
            "?fields=items.track(id,name,artists)&limit="+ options.limit +
            "&offset=" + options.offset;
        return await getPages(options);
    }
}
```

This way `getPages()` will only get resolved once all the awaits have been resolved which will be when `data.items.length !== 50`